# Create square box at random position using jquery

Tags: jquery

this is my code, my code gerenate square box at random position but it made clone every time i hit click. i want to gerenate square every time i click on button. While , i am getting clone when i click .How i can solve this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SYST24444</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">


        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body, html {
    width: 960;
    height: 100%;
}
div.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
}
div.exploding {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
            </style>

</head>


<body>
    <button id="button">Blue</button>
    <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    makeDiv();

    function makeDiv() {    //random position
        var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
        var divsize = 100;
        var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - divsize)).toFixed();
        var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - divsize)).toFixed();
        $newdiv = $("<div class='exploding'></div>").css({
            'left': posx + 'px',
                'top': posy + 'px'
        });
        $("#button").click(function(){  //click function
       $newdiv.appendTo('body').ready(function(){


            makeDiv();
        });
    });
    };
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. What is not working exactly ? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can move `click` handler outside of `makeDiv` function, return `$newdiv` from `makeDiv()` call, then chain `.appendTo("body" /* or other selector */)` to `makeDiv()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  makeDiv().appendTo("body");

  function makeDiv() { //random position
    var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
    var divsize = 100;
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - divsize)).toFixed();
    $newdiv = $("<div class='exploding'></div>").css({
      "left": posx + "px",
      "top": posy + "px"
    });
    return $newdiv
  };

  $("#button").click(function() { //click function
    makeDiv().appendTo("body");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>SYST24444</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      width: 960;
      height: 100%;
    }
    div.box {
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: orange;
    }
    div.exploding {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>

</head>


<body>
  <button id="button">Blue</button>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      makeDiv().appendTo("body");

      function makeDiv() { //random position
        var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
        var divsize = 100;
        var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - divsize)).toFixed();
        var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - divsize)).toFixed();
        $newdiv = $("<div class='exploding'></div>").css({
          'left': posx + 'px',
          'top': posy + 'px'
        });
        return $newdiv

      };
      $("#button").click(function() { //click function
        makeDiv().appendTo("body");
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```